# Navigate to a new page with React when I click on a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to navigate from welcome page to the login page, I created the 2 pages and now I want to navigate to the login page when I click on the Login button.

Here is the welcome page code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    logo: {
        width: '120px',
        height: '120px',
    },
    loginButton: {
        right: '50px',
    }
});

export default function Welcome() {
const classes = useStyles()
return (
        <div>
        <Box style={{ width: '100%' }} display="flex" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center" >

            <Box flexGrow={1}>
            <img src={require('../logo.svg')} className={classes.logo} />
            </Box>

            <Box>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.loginButton}>
                Login
            </Button>
            </Box>

        </Box>
</div>
```

And here is the Login component ( not yet finished ):

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      '& > *': {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        width: '25ch',
      },
    },
  }));

export default function Login() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <div>
            <TextField id="email" label="Enter email" />
            <TextField id="password" label="Enter password" />
        </div>
    )
}
```

PS: I'm using react material ui library

Comment: What is the problem you are facing ? React router is easy to use I guess.

Comment: How can I move to the login page in this case, can you suggest a solution ?

Comment: <Router>

            <Route path="/login" component={Login}>

            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.loginButton}>
                Login
            </Button>

            </Route></Router>

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You are doing great, and also you have written your `Welcome` and `Login`, `React functional components` very well.

To `navigate programmatically` to another page you have to use `history` object provided by `React Router DOM`.
And create a function that is can be executed using any button `onClick` method.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';


export default function Login() {

   const classes = useStyles();
   const loginHandler(){
       // handle your login logic
       history.push('/help'); // use either relative or absolute path both will work,navigate to help page or wherever want to navigate
   };

   return (
       <div>
            <TextField id="email" label="Enter email" />
            <TextField id="password" label="Enter password" />
            <button onClick={loginHandler}>Login</button>
       </div>
   );
}
```

Comment: The problem is not in the login component, it is not finished yet. I just want to navigate from the first page to the login page when I click on the Login button.

Comment: @AlaBenAicha I didn't mention that, there is a problem with `Login Component`, try this it will work like butter. Just put your `route path` to `history.push` method argument.

Answer (score 1):

You were really close with your comment reply:

`<Router> <Route path="/login" component={Login}> <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.loginButton}> Login </Button> </Route></Router>`

The way that works for me is to make a router file with a constant that contains my routers. It would look like this:

**Router.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from " *wherever your login is* ";
import Welcome from " *wherever your welcome is* ";

const Router = () => (
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Welcome} />
    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
  </div>
);

export default Router;
```

You would then make the only thing in your **App.js** file the router:

**App.js**

```
import Router from " *where you put your router file* ";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <Router>
            <Router />
         </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Finally, you would make your button a link to the designated url in your router:

**Welcome.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"; 
//^this import is important

...

<Button component={Link} to='/login' variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.loginButton}>
Login
</Button>
```

That should set you off. I'm kind of new to this as well so tell me if something is broken.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not working. When I click on the button it doesn't change the page. but now when I go to localhost/login it shows the Login page.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am not familiar with Material ui syntax. I made a minor edit in welcome.js on the button component that should work for material.